# Is there a better way to determine something is a module in python

Tags: python, introspection

I have the name of an 'thing' in python. I want to check if this 'thing' is a module or not. I can do it with the below code:

```
mod = eval(module_name)
print inspect.ismodule(mod)
```

I don't like the idea of calling eval. Is there a better way to get from the module_name, which is a string, to the actual module object?

Comment: What do you mean by "the name of an 'thing'". Do you have a string that is a module name? Do you have a variable, and want to check if the variable is a module? Clarify, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try build-in `__import__` function:

```
>>> __import__('aaa')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('aaa')
ImportError: No module named aaa
>>> __import__('os')
<module 'os' from 'C:\Python26\lib\os.pyc'>
```

So you code might look like next:

```
try:
    __import__(mod_name)
    print 'Such a module exists'
except ImportError:
    print 'No such module'
```

Comment: While find_module is a better solution, thanks for reminding me about `__import__`. I just replaced an `exec('import %s as something' % var)`.

Answer (score 3):

Better yet, forget about `__import__`'ing it, and just see if it exists. :)

Now, I don't know if this is actually much faster, however it's what I would do. `__import__` at the core uses `imp.find_module()` anyways.

```
import imp
try:
    imp.find_module('module')
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.exit('No such module')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from types import ModuleType

print type(datetime) == ModuleType
```

Edit: Sorry, misread the question. "name of a thing" is not what this example is using.